# Segmentation fault output is suppressed when piping stdin into a function. Why?

Tags: bash, command-line

Let's define a function to execute a binary:

```
function execute() { ./binary; }
```

Then define a second function to pipe a text file into the first function:

```
function test() { cat in.txt | execute; }
```

If `binary` crashes with a segfault, then calling `test` from the CLI will result in a `139` return code, but the error - "Segmentation fault" - will not be printed to the terminal.

"Segmentation fault" does get printed if we define `test` to call `binary` directly:

```
function test() { cat in.txt | ./binary; }
```

It also gets printed if we define to call `execute` without piping stdin into it:

```
function test() { execute; }
```

Finally, it also gets printed if we redirect `in.txt` into `execute` directly instead of through a pipe:

```
function test() { execute <in.txt; }
```

This was tested on Bash 4.4. Why is that?

Comment: FWIW, I can confirm the same behaviour with Bash 5.0.3.

Comment: Upon further investigation, this seems to be related to whether the shell is running in interactive or non-interactive mode. The error is printed in non-interactive mode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This diagnostic message is generated by the interactive shell's [job control](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Job-Control) system, for the benefit of the user - it's not from the underlying program that crashed. When you pipe into a shell function a [subshell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Execution-Environment) is spawned to run the function, and this subshell is not treated as user-facing. If you call the function normally, it runs within the original shell, and the message is printed.

You can test this out by disabling job control in your current shell

```
set +m
```

and then running `./binary` again: now it won't print anything there either. Re-enable job control with `set -m`.

Even a bare subshell has the same effect:

```
( : ; ./binary )
```

will print no diagnostic (two commands are required in there to avoid a subshell-eliding optimisation). Piping *out* of the function does it too.

Job control is disabled in the subshell, and even with it enabled manually, it's silenced. This is an unfortunate gap in the system. In a non-interactive shell the message would always be reported through a different mechanism, and anywhere else in an interactive shell it would as well.

---

If printing the diagnostic is important to you, making a script instead of a function will allow you to make sure it's always included. Since you're using the function in a pipeline, you can't do anything that requires a function anyway, so there's not a major cost to doing so.

---

I wouldn't go quite as far as to say this is a bug. One possible reason to behave in this way is to make [command substitution `$(...)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution), which also runs a subshell, behave appropriately:

```
foo=$(echo|test)
```

shouldn't result in the diagnostic message being stored in `foo`, so that pipeline failures result in empty expansions. Another is as a way to temporarily suppress the diagnostic messages deliberately.